# How to create multiple log files in laravel?

Tags: laravel

Like the state itself, I want to create multiple Log files for different processes.
I am using Laravel-8.
I have also created the 1 logging file with the help of logging.php in the config folder.

I want to keep track of my created commands with their own separate log file.

How can I create my separate log file for that commands?

I did this by having only a log for daily. "config/logging.php"

```
'channels' => [
    'stack' => [
        'driver' => 'stack',
        'channels' => ['daily'],
        'ignore_exceptions' => false,
    ]...,
 ]
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You should use `config/logging.php` to create custom channel for each command
e.g.

```
    'CHANNEL_NAME' => [
        'driver' => 'single',
        'path' => storage_path('logs/LOG_FILE_NAME.log'),
        'level' => 'DESIRED_LEVEL', 
    ],
```

and change `CHANNEL_NAME`, `LOG_FILE_NAME` and `DESIRED_LEVEL` values as you want.

**Note:** `'level' => 'DESIRED_LEVEL'` is optional. it can be single level or array of [levels (laravel v8.x)](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/logging#log-levels).

Then when you want to log anything in your command class, Log like following code

**Usage:**

```
    Log::channel('CHANNEL_NAME')
        ->info('Something happened!');
```

Answer (score 1):

Below code will generate custom log file.

```
try{
        //Your code here
}catch(\Exception $e){
        $cusLog = new Logger('stack');
                        $err_file_name = $task_id."_".time();
                        $syncHistory['file_name'] = $err_file_name;
                        $cusLog->pushHandler(new StreamHandler(storage_path('logs/'.$err_file_name.'.log')), Logger::INFO);
                        $cusLog->info('error', ['Exception'=>$e->getTraceAsString(),'message'=>$e->getMessage()]);
    }
```

Hope this will be useful.

Comment: Hi bro, the code is right work. Can you tell me `$syncHistory` has some effect?